# Length of index suggests different number of rows compared to looping through and printing index in Pandas DF

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas data frame. The number of rows are:

```
len(df.index)
```

529

Also, shape shows:

```
df.shape
```

(529, 5)

But if I loop through:

```
for i in df.index:
    print(i)
```

It prints:

```
0
1
2
...
728
729
732
```

Suggesting 732 rows. Same with iterrows():

```
for ind, col in df.iterrows():
    print(ind)
```

It prints:

```
0
1
2
...
728
729
732
```

Comment: Try `len([i for i in df.reset_index(drop=True).index])`, that should give the same result

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your indices are not necessarily sequential -- e.g., you have

```
729
732
```

I'm guessing you filtered a larger dataframe?

Answer (score 1):

As you see index can jump, e.g. `729` to `732`. Your data looks something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(10).reshape(5,2), index=[0,1,4,5,10])
```

which is:

```
    0  1
0   0  1
1   2  3
4   4  5
5   6  7
10  8  9
```

The index values does not cover all integer (range) values.